# Workflow for incompatible packages in SublimeText 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, package-control

I have two workflows for using SublimeText: one is for Python development and one is LaTeX document writing. I love using the `SublimeREPL` package when I'm doing Python and I love using `LaTeXTools` + `sublime-text-2-buildview` packages for LaTeX coding.

However, two of these packages (`SublimeREPL` and `sublime-text-2-buildview`) are simply incompatible and SublimeText crashes when I have them both installed. I've resorted to removing/installing the packages that aren't relevant for the project I'm working, but it's kind of annoying.

Is there anyway to have two separate Sublime "profiles" with different packages active under different profiles? This way, I could choose a "Python" profile which would launch ST with my Python packages or choose a "LaTeX" profile that launches ST with my LaTeX packages. I'm also open to other solutions, so long as they're more convenient than removing/installing packages every time I want to change workflows.

Comment: You could just use two portable sublime texts. So each would have its own packages, settings, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try:

## [Package Bundler](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Package%20Bundler)

---

> This package allows you to have multiple package sets.
>
> When you're doing some PHP, you don't need Ruby packages.
>
> With this package, you can create multiple presets of “ignored_packages” that you can load at will.